# Accessing Ubuntu desktop from WIndows through RDP and without monitor

Tags: remote-desktop, monitor, rdp

I installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on a PC. In Settings - Sharing, I activated Remote Desktop and Remote Control.

On my Windows 11 PC, I configured the remote desktop to access the Ubuntu PC that is on the same local network, using the IP address.

Everything works fine, my Ubuntu screen is replicated in a window on Windows.

Now, I want to run the Ubuntu PC without a monitor and manage it from the Windows RDP. But as soon as I remove the monitor on the Ubuntu PC, the window in my Windows 11 PC disapears.

I haven't found a solution to that problem. Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

tl/dr: I couldn't get rdp to work but xrdp does what I wanted.

I'm afraid I was never able to get rdp to work. I gave up and used a vnc connection which worked without a monitor, but only if I was already logged in locally. In trying to resolve that I found a post stating only works if a user is logged in locally and xRDP works only if there are NO users logged in locally. I already had 22.04 server installed with the default gui, and I've only bothered to use it on my home network, but it's done what I spent days trying to get anything else to do.

Not a proper solution, I know, but 3 months with no answers seemed even more disheartening.